# How can I say "to focus"/"to concentrate"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

How can I translate "to focus" (or "to concentrate") in these examples?

- I can't focus because of the noise.
- We have to focus on trying to solve this problem right now.
- She is focusing on her goals.

In dictionaries I found "koncentrigxi" and "fokusi", but when I look in PIV I feel like they are tranlsations of the scientifical terms *to focus* and to *concentrate*, and not the kind of verb I am looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, PIV does give that impression for *koncentriĝi* (I can't find "fokusi" in either PIV or ReVo), and most (but not all) of the results in the Tekstaro involve concentrating a specific thing, whether literal or metaphorical. However, [ReVo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) defines *koncentri sin* as "*Streĉi la intelektajn fortojn super solvota problemo*" and gives *koncentriĝi* as a synonym (among other definitions), with the example sentence

> *la vido de viaj streĉitaj mienoj malhelpas min serioze koncentriĝi*

In practice, *koncentriĝi* is the more common word for that meaning, and is so used in some courses, such as ["Ana Renkontas"](http://lernu.net/eo/biblioteko/118/4) on lernu.net.

> Ana: Buboj, ĉesu! Ni devas nun koncentriĝi je la franca testo.
>   Klasamiko2: Kiel diri "tre bela" en la franca?
>   Klasamiko3: Mi scias kiel diri "Mi amas vin Ana", se iu volas scii...

But if you want to be more precise, you can say "koncentri la/mian atenton pri/je tio".

Answer (score 1):

The two verbs *atenti* and *celi* could be useful even though they are transitive.

> atenti (tr)
>
> 1 Teni siajn vidon, aŭdon k intelekton fiksitaj al io

and

> celi (tr)
>
> [...]
>
> 3 Direkti sian agadon, deziron, volon al io, kion oni penas atingi aŭ plenumi

I would use *atenti* for not being distracted and I would use *celi* for specifying goals. Hence the sentences would be

- Mi ne povas **atenti** ion pro la bruo.
- Ni devas **celi** provi solvi la problemojn nun.
- Ŝi **celas** siajn celojn.